# Getting Custom SuperView in a touch event?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on a small game where i want to do some functionality on the super view .. and the super view is a custom class i.e. [Reflection View..](https://github.com/nicklockwood/ReflectionView) and want to hide the reflection when the user moves the view..

Here is what i have done..
**(Check the Comment in the Code for Details)**

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"Touch Began");
    frame2 = dragImageView1.frame;
     NSLog(@"uiview origin: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(frame2.origin));
     // here i want to get the superview Programatically because i will work on multiple such views and [touch view].superview does not give me the ReflectionView Functions
     [_reflectionView1 hideReflection];
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];


      if ([[touch view] tag]!=0) {
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [[touch view] setFrame:CGRectMake(frame2.origin.x, frame2.origin.y, 125.0 * 1.1, 135.0 * 1.1)];
    } else {
        [[touch view] setFrame:CGRectMake(frame2.origin.x, frame2.origin.y, 52.08 * 1.1, 63.28 * 1.1)];
    }
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[touch view].superview]; 
      }
}
```

Comment: check the comment in the code.....

Comment: You need to typecast the view if you want to use any extra methods added by the subclass. Something like this: `[(ReflectionView *)touch.view.superview someArbitraryMethod];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 0x7fffff Mentioned you need to cast the Super view to your Custom View. Like

```
[(ReflectionView *)touch.view.superview updateReflection];
```

Use this if you are sure that where you are calling this where the superview will always be ReeflectionView or else your application will crash if you are using this where the superview is not a Reflection.
then add this to your code

```
if(touch.view.superview isEqual:[ReflectionView class])
{
   [(ReflectionView *)touch.view.superview updateReflection];
}
```